# Add html elements into div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got 3 nested divs.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="innerWrapper">
      <div id="inner"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

I need to add html via jQuery./ So I use

```
$('#wrapper').html('<img src="profile.png"/>');
```

But when I do that the `innerWrapper` and `inner` divs disappears. How can I add `<img src="profile.png"/>` instead of replacing the divs inside `wrapper`?

Comment: Use `append()`. `$('#wrapper').append('<img src="profile.png"/>');` or `prepend()` if you want it before the `innerWrapper`

Comment: `$('#wrapper').append('<img src="profile.png"/>');` - There are multiple methods to do it.. but it really depends on where you want the new element to be added to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `.appand()` instead of `.html()`, `.html()` will remove the previous elements.

```js
$('#wrapper').append('<img src="profile.png"/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">wrapper
   <div id="innerWrapper">innerWrapper
      <div id="inner"></div>inner
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `append()` instead of `html()`

```js
$('#wrapper').append('<img src="profile.png" titile="image"/>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <div id="wrapper">
   <div id="innerWrapper">innerwrapper
  <div id="inner">inner</div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `append` instead of `html`

```
$('#wrapper').append('&lt;img src="profile.png"/&gt;');
```